# Why does this loop only once?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
while count > 0:
     if count = 0:
        return n
     elif count < 0:
        print(" ") # prints empty if n is below 0
     else:
        count = count - 1
        collect += math.ceil((n - 5)/2)
     return collect
```

The inputs are (1003, 3) - result is 499, which means it just loop once and subtracts 5 and then divides by 2, then it stops. Anyone know why?

Comment: `=` isn't `==`.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: You're also not showing your entire code. Inputs _to what_? `return` _from what_? Do you really want to `return` inside your loop?

Comment: @Chris That shouldn't matter since `count > 0` in the loop anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner conditionals don't make sense with the while. And you have a return statement in the loop, so yes, it only looped once.

Start with this

```
import math

n, count = (1003, 3)
print("N = " + str(n))
while count > 0:
  n = math.ceil((n - 5) / 2)  # Update this to do whatever your logic is
  print(count, n)
  count -= 1
if n < 0:
  print("N is negative")
else:
  print("N = " + str(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

First, your syntax isn't indented evenly.

Second, your if statement have `=` instead of `==`. The first one for assigning values to variables, the second is for checking equality.

Third, you have a return statement that's going to exit from whatever function this loop is inside.